# Basic algebra gone out the window

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm really embarrassed to ask this - my apologies.

In a piece of software I'm writing, I am using the following:

$Y = X+\frac{X}{10}N$

That's all fine - but how do I calculate X when I know Y and N?

I know it's really basic, but for some reason I get stuck half-way through moving the equation around.

Comment: Please clarify, is it $\frac{X}{10N}$ or $\frac{X}{10}N$ ? (Parentheses are hella important!)

Comment: SOrry, it is Y = X + ((X/10)*N)

Comment: Note then that $Y=X(1+\frac{N}{10})$; thus, $X=\frac{Y}{1+\frac{N}{10}}$ ...

Comment: Spot on, that works perfectly.

Comment: @J.M., @palmaceous: In the interest of not having an unanswered question, could you post-answer-and-accept?

Comment: @Arturo, done now.

Comment: Are X,Y,N suppose to be integer types? Or are they floats? I am asking this because X/10 might become 0, when 1 <= X <= 10, when X is an integer, depending on your programming language. So the mathematical formula might actually not work!

Answer (score 2):

If $Y=X+\frac{X}{10}N=X\left(1+\frac{N}{10}\right)$, then $X=\frac{Y}{1+\frac{N}{10}}$ .